# Creating a website setup 'wizard'

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, installation

I am looking to create a setup for my website that a webmaster can complete to setup the required features of the webserver, such as the database, an administrator account, etc.

What I have planned so far is a $_GET variable will automatically be assigned (if not already!) to the user, the $_GET variable will be called something such as $_GET['step'] to represent what step the user is on. This will also allow me to easily display the specific form(s) for that specific step. For example, display the 'Database Setup' form on step 1, but then on step 2 display the 'Create an Administrator' form. I would do this by using switch statements.

However, if there was an error with the information that the user has given, such as a connection cannot be established with the given information, how would I check the information that was inputted and then display an error to the user, forcing them to change the information in the form, if they have been redirected to step 2 when they submitted the form?

Thanks,

Kieron

EDIT: Here is a Pastebin link to what I have so far: http://pastebin.com/Y6YSTrgR

I couldn't put it directly in this post as it wasn't formatting properly.

Comment: Your question isn't really good, you have to show some coding. But according to what I understood, you should use the `if`, `else if` and `else` statements

Comment: @KANAYOAUSTINKANE `switch`/`case` is also a perfectly valid way of approaching this.

Comment: I have updated the post with what I have so far, to give a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You've not shared enough technical detail for this question to be helpful, however if I understand you correctly then you could save each step into the session so that you can go back if necessary. This way you could persist the data if the user finishes the last step. If the user doesn't finish the last step, nothing has changed on the server.

Really you need to tell us more about the system, such as which framework you're using (if any) and describe more about how the overall process should work.